# How to capture screenshot of test application

Tags: testcomplete

Is there any way to capture screenshot of test application and save that screenshot to particular location via script in testcomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Call the [`.Picture`](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/72731/) method of your application's main window to capture its image, then call the image's [`.SaveToFile`](https://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/74446/) method.

```js
// JScript
var img = Sys.Process("notepad").Window("Notepad").Picture();
img.SaveToFile("C:\\Work\\img.png");
```